# Can not install memcache for PHP 5.5.6 on Win7 64-bit with XAMPP 1.8.3

Tags: php, windows, dll, module, memcached

Does anyone know the place where needed files can be found? I've spent hours searching but everything is useless :(

I've got memcache that I've used with php 5.3, but for php 5.5.6 it does not work.

And when starting Apache it gives me

`PHP Startup error: memcachee: Unable to initialize module. 
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match`

Is there somewhere the needed php_memcache.dll for my platform (PHP 5.5.6 on Win7 64-bit with XAMPP 1.8.3)?

Answer (score 2):

Success!

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/

I'm running Apache 2.4.9 x64 / PHP 5.5.10 x64 (thread safe) so I used [this one](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/php_memcache-3.0.8-5.5-ts-vc11-x64.zip).